Can I replace a 60W high output fluorescent tube with a regular 40 watt tube?
Can I replace a 60W high output fluorescent tube with a regular 40 watt fluorescent tube?

Aside from what Ecnerwal says, in the 48-96" tube format, the HO terminals (plastic oval with 2 terminals in them) are incompatible with normal terminals (a 1/4" diameter all-metal "nub" for 48-96" tubes, and two pins 1/2" apart for 12-48" tubes, yes, there's an overlap).  This is so people don't mix-n-match HO and standard tubes.
You would need to change both the ballast and the terminal ("tombstone").
I'm all for staying with real fluorescent if your usage is infrequent. However, if your power supply is 120V-ish, you may be better off switching the fixture permanently to direct-wire LED.  If HO-socket LEDs are not available, change the tombstones to the normal sockets.
LED conversion is problematic if supply voltage is higher, particularly 277-347V, and in that case you may be forced to stay with real fluorescent (or come up with a buck transformer to power 120V LEDs).

Not without also replacing the ballast with an appropriate ballast for a 40W bulb.
The odds that the present ballast is compatible with a 40W bulb are non-zero but very, very small. Some few electronic ballasts can adapt to multiple bulb types, but that would more likely be other high output bulb types, if any, not a normal output bulb.

You might be right, but a living room floor lamp came to mind for me, so no ballast is at play. Does something about the question suggest otherwise?

High Output and Very High Output are standard designations for linear tube bulbs commonly found in High-Bay (warehouse is the typical application) fixtures (which are sold to the general public at blue and orange box stores as well as via the internet, without even getting into the "grow-ops" type suppliers...)

I revised the question to refer to tubes. There's nothing bulbous about them. I suggest that Ecnerwal follow suit for clarity.
